# Does serial voting script work perfectly?

Tags: bug, reputation, voting

Have a look at [this user's reputation tab](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/753/sports-fan?tab=reputation&StartDate=2013-10-09) of last few days. You can see that the user is upvoted serially for last few days. May be only two upvote doesn't considered as serial voting. There are some cases where he is voted more than two times. E.g. Oct. 9, Oct. 16, Oct. 17, Oct. 18. But not *all votes* are reversed properly. Only votes of date Oct. 18 are reversed. So I think the voting fraud script doesn't work properly.

<sub>PS: I don't have any problem with that user (even he is a good SE user IMHO.), but I am concerned for voting fraud script.</sub>

Comment: We don't ordinarily discuss details of the serial upvoting detection and prevention mechanisms - in fact, most of the details are known only by the developers. Suffice it to say that this is a small site and we're usually aware of things.

Comment: @MichaelMyers - True. I didn't say that I want details of serial voting mechanisms (i.e. how does it work). I just want to know whether it works fine or there are some issues in the script. See yesterday's (2013-10-20) rep details once again a serial voting. But it is not reversed.

Comment: @MichaelMyers, Please find that guy and remove him. I'm getting serial upvoting reversal two times.